# Execute function in this same element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, elementor

I'm new here, and in Jquery ...
I am using Wordpress to create a website and I have a Jquery function for opening cards, these cards have a plus button, and clicking that button opens a description of the card ...
So far so ok, but all the cards have the same classes (on the button, and the description) and pulling it on the page I need to use them by clicking on one of the buttons it opens all the descriptions of the other cards ... can i make it open only the card description of the button i clicked?

Code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(this).ready(function(){
  $(".abrir-btn").click(function(){
    $(".conteudo-div").show(200);
    $(".abrir-btn").hide();
    $(".fechar-btn").show();
    $(".listing-nucleados").css("background-color", "#FFE500");
    $(".listing-nucleados").css("border-color", "#fff");
  });
$(".fechar-btn").click(function(){
    $(".conteudo-div").hide(200);
    $(".abrir-btn").show();
    $(".fechar-btn").hide();
    $(".listing-nucleados").css("background-color", "#fff");
    $(".listing-nucleados").css("border-color", "#EBEBEB");
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: how about use `siblings()` jquery api?

https://api.jquery.com/siblings/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, the buttons as well as the `.listing-lucleados` are both wrapped inside a parent element (let's call it `.my-parent` here). You can do the following:

```
$(this).ready(function(){
  $(".abrir-btn").click(function(){
    $(this).hide();
    var parent = $(this).parents('.my-parent');
    parent.find(".conteudo-div").show(200);
    parent.find(".fechar-btn").show();
    parent.find(".listing-nucleados").css("background-color", "#FFE500").css("border-color", "#fff");
  });
  $(".fechar-btn").click(function(){
    $(this).hide();
    var parent = $(this).parents('.my-parent');
    parent.find(".conteudo-div").hide(200);
    parent.find(".abrir-btn").show();
    parent.find(".listing-nucleados").css("background-color", "#fff").css("border-color", "#EBEBEB");
  });
});
```

Basically, what this does is going up the DOM tree to the parent element wrapping the show/hide buttons, as well as the list to show/hide. Then, from the parent element, find its descendants (I'm not saying direct children, because I do not know that much about your HTML structure) and apply the operation only to elements of this class inside the parent element.

Answer (score 0):

In the function performed after clicking the button find a common ancestor of both elements - the button and the description - using [`closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/). 
Having an ancestor, find in it elements with the class `.abrir-btn`, `.fechar-btn` or `.conteudo-div`.

Example HTML:

```
<div class="content-outer">

    <!-- the order inside is not important -->
    <button class="abrir-btn" >show</button>
    <button class="fechar-btn" >hide</button>
    <div class="conteudo-div">...</div>

</div>
```

```
$(this).ready(function(){
    $(".abrir-btn").click(function( event ){
        var parent = $(event.target).closest(".content-outer");
        if ( !parent.length )
            return;
        parent.find(".conteudo-div").show(200);
        parent.find(".abrir-btn").hide();
        parent.find(".fechar-btn").show();
        parent.find(".listing-nucleados").css("background-color", "#FFE500").css("border-color", "#fff");
      });
});
```